# Parallax effect not working on mobile chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

can you help me with my code, my parallax effect working fine on any browser except on mobile google chrome app.

```
 #collage_container{
    height:100%;
    background: url(images/collage.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
    }

<div id="collage_container">
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/mypinoy_logo.png"></div>
    <div class="tagline"><img src="images/tagline.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know your answer has been sitting for some time without an answer, but here is a link that was really helpful to me: [Performant Parallaxing](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/performant-parallaxing).

Good luck!